# How does Best Partition Communication Complexity behave under input transformations?

Tags: communication-complexity

I'm looking for references about the behavior of communication complexity under input transformations. A specific toy example of the kind of question I'm interested in is the following.

Let $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ be a Boolean function over variables $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $g(y_1,...,y_n,z_1,...,z_n)$ be a Boolean function over variables $\{y_1,...,y_n\} \cup \{z_1,....,z_n\}$ such that for each $a_1,...,a_n\in \{0,1\}^n$, 
$$f(a_1,...,a_n) = 1$$ if and only if there exists $b_1,...,b_n\in \{0,1\}^n$ and $c_1,...,c_n\in \{0,1\}^n$ such that 
$$g(b_1,...,b_n,c_1,...,c_n)=1 \mbox{ and } a_i = b_i \vee c_i \mbox{ for each $i\in \{1,...,n\}$}$$.

**Question:** Assume that the best partition communication complexity of $f$ is $d$. Is it true that the
best partition communication complexity of $g$ is at least $d$?

Comment: A protocol for $g$ in particular has to work when all the $z_i$ variables are $0$, in which case you get a protocol for $f$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I had asked the question in the wrong way. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: Have you tried simple examples? E.g., $f=\textsf{AND}_n$, $g=\textsf{AND}_{2n}$ while setting $c_2=...=c_n=1$ and $c_1=f(a_1,...,a_n)$ for all $(a_i)_i$.

Comment: Do you know this paper? https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il//report/2012/131/ Especially Section 2 could be relevant, which suggests that the answer to your question is yes (at least with $\Omega(d)$). Without such methods, proving lower bounds for compositions is hard in CC.

Comment: Also see the later paper https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2012/171/.